# Formula for a special case with Stocks/Volume/Prices

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I’m writing a stock trading style program and I’m trying to add a feature for a special case.

If you make a purchase and the price goes down, there is a volume you can purchase that would cancel out loses incurred from the bad trade, if the price were to go back up from the point of the second trade price.

For example: If you buy 2 shares of a stock at 100 dollars; You have 200 worth of value.
If the stock goes down to 80 dollars, you only have 160$ worth of value; You have lost 40 dollars of value.

If you believe the price will return to 90 (chosen because it is the middle range price between the two), you could gain 12.5% on all of the shares that you bought at 80, and you would even out with all of the shares bought at 100, if you bought 2 or more shares at 80.

So in this case you bought (2 * 100) + (2 * 80) = 360. 360/4 = 90 to break even and anything higher becomes a gain.

I need to figure out an equation to describe this relationship. I can think it through on a case by case basis, but I can’t think of a way to abstract it into one formula.

The variables I have available:

- Total Funds available
- Bad Trade volume
- Bad Trade price (Has to be greater than market price for this to trigger)
- Market price
- Expected Growth, 1%, 5%, (((trade price + market price) / 2)/market price)

Variables That I need answered:

- Volume to purchase to cancel losses when the expected growth price is reached.

I want to run it for at least four different levels, i.e. if market value grows by 1%, 5%, or if the value is split between market and buy price (like my example).

I also need to solve it for the percentage to answer the question: how much growth would be required to cancel out the bad trade, if the user bought in with all user funds at market price?

Comment: This smacks of what investors call "dollar cost averaging".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $p_1$ denote the original, buy price.  Let $p_2$ denote the current price.  Let $p_3$ denote the expected growth price.  Let $x$ denote the number of shares we originally bought, and $y$ denote the number of shares we need to buy to break even.

At the time the price becomes $p_3$, our (negative) gains from our original purchase will be $x(p_3-p_1)$.  Our (positive) gains from our new purchase will be $y(p_3-p_2)$.  If our goal is to break even, then their sum must be zero, i.e. $x(p_3-p_1)+y(p_3-p_2)=0$.  We may rearrange this as $y=x\frac{p_1-p_3}{p_3-p_2}$.

Comment: Thank you! It seems so simple now after reading that. Thank you for that excellent explanation.